# REST HTTP Response code for a resource that the user is not authorised to access

Tags: rest, security, http

Suppose user A creates a private resource at, for example, `/books/somebooktitle`

If user B attempts to access the resource at `/books/somebooktitle` what code should be returned?

HTTP403: Permission denied seems obvious BUT, does this not leak information to user B that someone has created a book and named that book with the title "somebooktitle"? That's two pieces of information that user B shouldn't technically be entitled to.

HTTP404: hides the fact that the book exists.

Is there best practice?

Comment: If you're concerned about leaks, you also need to be careful about not being vulnerable to [timing attacks](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/timing-attack). If there is a significant time difference between a book which actually does not exist and a book for which the requester is unauthorized, then you're still leaking the information even if you return a 404 Not Found in both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no best practice for precisely the reason you cited in your question. It becomes a judgement call based on the kind of information you might expose. If hinting that "somebooktitle" might leak security-sensitive information, or violate a copyright or other kind a law, then go with a `404 Not Found` response. You also have the option of redirecting the user to a general purpose search page that results in a `200 OK` response. Which kind of response you choose will be driven by security, legal and business considerations. There is no one-size-fits-all solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have reputation to comment on Greg's excellent answer, so posting this as an answer.

Just adding a link to the spec:
[https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#:~:text=10.4.5%20404%20Not%20Found](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#:%7E:text=10.4.5%20404%20Not%20Found)
Which suggests that it is appropriate to use a 404 response to mask the reason that the request is denied.

Comment: very helpful thank you